# NSString problems

Tags: string, random, nsmutablestring

I have problems with a simple NSString on Mac OS X:

```
NSString *letters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
myString = [myString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%c", [letters characterAtIndex:3]];
```

When I try to access this string again, Xcode is returning `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`
This error just occures, when I'm using the format @"%c"
When I'm using @"%@", sometimes the same error, sometimes this string: `control 0x10040a480` and sometimes this:

```
{(
    <CFRunLoopObserver 0x10015ac60 [0x7fff70731ee0]>{locked = No, valid = Yes, activities = 0x21, repeats = Yes, order = 0, callout = _ZL15FlushAllBuffersP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv (0x7fff88a147d4), context = <CFRunLoopObserver context 0x0>}
)}
```

The errors occur randomly even, if I don't change anything in the code and re-run it.

I try to get a random String by doing:

```
randomString = @"";
    NSString *letters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        randomString = [randomString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%c", [letters characterAtIndex:(rand()%[letters length])]];
    }
```

randomString is declared in header.h
I also tried using a NSMutableString but that didn't work too.
Every time I try to access the string (or mutable string) via `@"%@"` I'm getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

Any idea?
Hope somebody can help me!

Greets,
Julian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `myString` gets autoreleased before you access it.

You need to change:

```
myString = [myString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%c", [letters characterAtIndex:3]];
```

to:

```
myString = [[myString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%c", [letters characterAtIndex:3]] retain];
```

Remember to run `[myString release];` when you are done with it.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped! When do I have to release it? When I'm done with definition, do I still have to let them unreleased, until I don't need them anymore (When the Application terminates)?

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

define letters at top of file:

```
#define letters @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
```

then append a random character like this:

```
NSString *randomString = @"";

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{
    UInt64 index = rand() % [letters length];
    NSString *randomCharacter = [letters substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(index, 1)];
    randomString = [randomString stringByAppendingString:randomCharacter];
}

NSLog(@"%@", randomString);
```